# Handling form messages for Windows Mobile 6.5

Tags: c#, windows, forms, compact-framework, handler

I have a windows mobile application I want to fully close when the users clicks the "X" rather than hide it.

I've added the following method to my form, but it has errors. The code has been copied from somewhere else and if I'm totally honest, I'm not really sure how to use the form handlers etc properly, so I wondered if someone could help me?

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
if (m.Msg == 0x0005)
{ 
    // WM_SIZE
    if (m.WParam == new IntPtr(0x04))
    { 
        // SIZE_MINIMIZED
        this.Close();
    }
}
base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

> Error 1. "The type or namespace name 'Message' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
>
> Error 2. "'System.Windows.Forms.Form' does not contain a definition
>   for 'WndProc'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular case, the simplest way to solve the actual problem is just to set the `MinimizeBox` property of the `Form` to `false`. That turns the X button into a white circle with the text "Ok". Tapping that button will exit the form's Run loop by posting a Quit message, which will normally terminate the process unless you explicitly write code to do otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You can't override the WndProc in a Compact Framework Form or Control.  You've copied code from a desktop project.  For the compact Framework, it a bit more complex.  In many cases, just using a [`MessageWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446525.aspx) is enough to see the messages coming in for you to react (an example [can be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188736.aspx)).  If, however, you need to fully subclass, then it's a bit more complex.  Here's [an MSDN example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/netcfteam/archive/2005/05/23/421143.aspx) that subclasses a Control, though a Form would be the same.